# Distanciar imagem do texto em Button

Tags: android

tenho esse Buttoncom uma imagem  e texto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/notificacao"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/alarm"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/btNotificacao"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

tava querendo distânciar o reloginho do texto , tentei colocar um espaço antes do texto mais ignora o espaço

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Achei a solução.

```
android:drawablePadding="8dp"
```